# How to set progress bar when upload a file transfer to server

Tags: android, android-progressbar

How to create a progress bar when upload file to server in android.I am given below this code please help me.....When transfer my data to show a progress bar....Please solve my problem..This is my uploading file class...

```
    public void doFileUpload(File file) {


                FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

                try {  
                    client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);
                    Log.e("clientconnect", "" + client);
                    client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
                    Log.e("clientlogin", "" + client);
                    client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                    Log.e("clienttype", "" + client);
                    client.changeDirectory("/gg1/");
                    Log.i("", "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" + ("/gg1/"));


                    client.upload(file,new MyTransferListener());
                    Log.e("filenameupload", "" + file);



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        client.disconnect(true);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

            public void started() {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Upload Started ...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void transferred(int length) {


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transferred ..." + length,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void completed() {


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " completed ...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            public void aborted() {


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        " transfer aborted , please try again...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void failed() {


                System.out.println(" failed ...");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to extend `asynctask` for doing activities which uses internet

Your upload class typically would be like

```
 private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");

        btnUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return uploadFile(params[0]);
    }

    private String uploadFile(String name) {

        try {
        // FTP Upload code

    }

        } catch (IOException e) {

    }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

You call the instance of the class in the main thread

```
new UploadFileToServer().execute("filepath/filename");
```

the layout file would be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/view_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPercentage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_font"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/btn_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

HTH.